# Examples of transient chaos in the quasi-periodic route to chaos?

Tags: chaos-theory

I have read that transient chaos has been observed experimentally where a quasiperiodic steady state is involved (e.g. in Ytrium Crystals). I have also read about examples of equations which show transient chaos for the period doubling route to chaos. However, I am looking for examples of ODEs which admit quasiperiodic solutions and which exhbit transient chaos. However, I can't seem to find any and would be grateful for any pointers.

FOR A LITTLE CONTEXT:

I am simulating a system that has been shown to be chaotic for certain parameter values. Other value look periodic but upon estimating the correlation dimension I found that it was $\ge 2$ with a non-positive dominant Lyapunov exponent. This led me to conclude that the system must be quasiperiodic.

However, the "quasiperiodic" steady state is preceded by an erratic looking transient that resembles the system at chaotic parameter values.

Comment: Why don’t you calculate the second Lyapunov exponent of your dynamics? A quasiperiodic system must have at least two zero Lyapunov exponents.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Thanks, I will try that, but what I'm also looking for is precedence in the literature for transient chaos in quasiperiodic systems.

Answer (score 1):

You can always “cheat”:

1. Let $\dot{y} = f(y)$ with $f:ℝ^n→ℝ^n$ describe some system that exhibits transient chaos with a periodic attractor.
2. For some vector $z ∈ℝ^{2n}$, let $\hat{z}∈ℝ^n$ be the vector containing the first $n$ components of $z$ and $\check{z}∈ℝ^n$ be the vector containing the second $n$ components of $z$, i.e., $z_{n+1}, …, z_{2n}$.
3. Define $g$ such that $g_i(z) := f_i(\hat{z})$ for $i∈{1,…,n}$ and $g_i(z) := π·f_i(\check{z})$ for $i∈{n+1,…,2n}$.
4. Consider the dynamics described by $\dot{z}=g(z)$.

This dynamics is composed of two independent dynamics as described by $f$ running at different, incommensurable speeds. Hence this dynamics would have a quasiperiodic attractor and exhibit transient chaos, as long as one of the individual dynamics has not settled on its attractor.

If this is too much cheating for you, add a small coupling term between the two subsystems that is designed such that it vanishes on their respective attractors. If the term is sufficiently small, it should not affect the properties you are interested in. (Also it may help to keep in mind that every quasiperiodic motion can somehow be separated into independent periodic ones.)

Comment: Thank you, that is a helpful insight. The system does indeed have such a structure, with three different layers of time separation. My only issue is that all of the time separation parameters are rational (though the equations at each level of time separation are quite different). Would I be right in assuming that the difference in equation form could lead to to the incomensurability of the frequencies (without having any irrational system parameters)? The system is actually partially based on a Lotka_volterra model which has periodic solutions.

Comment: *Would I be right in assuming that the difference in equation form could lead to to the incomensurability of the frequencies (without having any irrational system parameters)?* – Yes, just consider the classical harmonic oscillator which has oscillates with a period of $2π$ without having any irrational number in its differential equation.

Comment: Thank you again! I had forgotten that I could simply couple two systems with incomensurable frequencies to get the desired effect.

Comment: Note though that the coupling I was mentioning is just the icing on the cake and has to be carefully crafted to achieve the desired effect. Plainly coupling two similar systems with incommensurable frequencies probably leads to some sort of synchrony and no quasiperiodicity.